Blazor Anchor Link Navigation Routing Issue
I was trying to create Anchor Link or Bookmark for some contents. My issue is on click bookmark href link it scroll and take me to content right but my problemit throws Unhandled Error throws on Blazor Page. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot parse the value '7900#headerC' as type 'System.Int32' for 'Wid'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot parse the value '7900#headerC' as type 'System.Int32' for 'Wid'.
Reproduction Link : https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYcoPuGRTwdhdiuh
I tried same as in trysnippet for my blazor demo page just add AnchorNavigation tag to my demo page and added javascript BlazorScrollToId in index.html others all same as trysnippet and its working is same in both. My AnchorNavigation.razor and BlazorScrollToId.js are from reference for blazor Anchor link. It doesn't seems like AnchorLink problem but its Navigation Routing issue
reference for blazor Anchor link : https://www.meziantou.net/anchor-navigation-in-a-blazor-application.htm
